# Error in setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

I'm trying to develop a login page, but I keep getting this error and I don't understand why.
I don't know what I am doing wrong but it seems that setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() is not working, I don't know if the problem is in the button that I create or something else.
Can someone help me, please?

**patient.login**

```
package com.example.dissertation;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class patient_login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;
    private EditText phone_number;
    private TextView login_feedback;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        ok();
    }

    public void ok(){
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phone = phone_number.getText().toString();

                if(phone.isEmpty()){
                    login_feedback.setText("Por favor, preencha para continuar...");
                }else{
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    button.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override // vê se o user já está login
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ligação com MainActivity
        if(mCurrentUser == null){
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(patient_login.this, MainActivity.class);
            homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish(); //garante que o utilizador não volta à MainActivity
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dissertation, PID: 30104
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dissertation/com.example.dissertation.patient_login}: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button
        at com.example.dissertation.patient_login.ok(patient_login.java:46)
        at com.example.dissertation.patient_login.onCreate(patient_login.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8290)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8269)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3657)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3813) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2308) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7898) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: Hey there, welcome to SO. can you share your xml file codes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have declared **"button"** **id** at wrong place instead of in `button` you have set it to `constraintLayout`. that's my guess from error message but if its not the case share xml file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, you have set the `button` id to the **constraint layout** instead of a **Button**. You need to set the id of the **Button** in your layout as `button`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that you are using a button from `android.wdget.Button` One of the solutions in your xml file create a button with the same parameters and in the same location but `androidx.appcompat.Button`